# Can't connect to Chrome Dev Tools debugger

Tags: node.js, jestjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have a web application built in nodejs and running on docker container. I am using Chrome Dev Tools to debug my applications and test cases using jest.

```
"test-debug": "NODE_ENV='test' node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 node_modules/.bin/jest --run-in-band --bail"
```

It works as expected at home, offline mode, and using mobile hotspot unless and until I connect it to my office wifi network.

I also tried changing to different port numbers but they didn't work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out we can't debug on Chrome Debugger tool when the connected wifi hosts are isolated.